# Yii2 - Get access permissions for another users

Tags: php, permissions, yii2, access-control

In Yii2 we can check access of current user for any permissions by `yii\web\User::can()` as follow:

```
if (\Yii::$app->user->can('createPost')) {  // user_id=1
    // create post
}
```

How can we check access for another users such as `user_id = 5` in yii2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
if (\Yii::$app->authManager->checkAccess($user_id, 'createPost')) {}
```